# Velocity JS and dynamic DOM content insertion sequence

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, velocity.js

I am relatively new to velocity JS. I want to introduce some characters (an object containing an image URL and a name) like a transition sequence with images and names coming alternatively from left and right. I have made the code and it works, however there is one major issue and I feel there is some conceptual mistake in my approach.

Unfortunately, I could not take a working code example out of the big system. But basically in Backbone JS I am selecting the element and setting its .html() to some content from DB and chaining this call with a call to velocity.

As an example:

```
@$eventResultAvatarContainer.html("<img src=#{@avatarURLs[0]}>").velocity('transition.bounceLeftIn', { duration: 2000, complete: @entryIntroduction })
```

which works but in the following sequence:

1. First the element shows for a split second in the container.
2. Then velocity's call animates the object in or out.

How can I get rid of 1. above i.e. before the chained call executes, is there a way to not have the element visible till velocity animation starts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be sure without seeing actual code, but try using `style="visibility:hidden;"` to hide the eventResultAvatarContainer before using `.css({visibility:'visible'})` to show them right before .velocity.

This makes sure the element is not rendered before velocity has a chance to act on it.

I did a jsfiddle to try to mockup your environment, you can use it to do further testing, or try to recreate your environment as much as possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/gdp2suet/2/